# Detecting web proxy security

Tags: security, networking

Various online resources offer proxy lists claiming that they offer various levels of anonymity. I'm trying to find out how this can be programmatically tested. I suspect the answer lies in headers. Would testing a proxy's security by running a sender/receiver and seeing what headers come through the proxy on the receiving end be a good approach?

**EDIT:** One good resource I found so far mentioning proxy headers: http://meatballwiki.org/wiki/AnonymousProxy

Comment: Look up 'browser fingerprinting' and also read [Defeating Browser Fingerprinting by spoofing the browser user agent and VPN](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/91166/30204).

Comment: @MichaelT - thank you for the info. It helped me write a web proxy checker with anonymity classifications using header analysis: [github](https://github.com/MaksimKneller/goodproxy)